# Coldfusion cfdirectory only lists some files in a directory when all the files are the same

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016, cfdirectory

I have a page that uses a `<cfdirectory` tag to display PDF files in a directory for a user to choose. The directory it is looking at contains folders each of which is named in mm-dd-yyyy format. The folders go from 07-28-2021 all the way back to 06-22-2015. Each folder contains a series of PDF files for that day.

The page with the cfdirectory tag displays all the files up to the 06-08-2020 folder. It will not display any of the subsequent files. Logically one would assume that since coldfusion will display some of the files that something must have changed with the files themselves after 06/08/2020 but I have compared the properties on the folders and files it will display with the ones that it will not and see no differences.

My cfdirectory tag looks like this:

```
<cfdirectory 
directory="D:\Domains\zzzz\POM\zzzz\POM\" 
name = "directoryFileList" 
sort = "name DESC, size ASC">
```

So it will display all the files up to the ones in the `D:\Domains\zzzz\POM\zzzz\POM\06-08-2020` folder. It will not display the files in the `D:\Domains\zzzz\POM\zzzz\POM\06-09-2020` folder or any files dated after that.

We are using ColdFusion 2016. I am at a loss as to why it will list files only up to a certain date. Is this a problem with caching? Is there some hidden file attribute that I'm not seeing when I view the properties? I appreciate any help!

Comment: Does reversing the sort give you the same folders? or do you then get the ones you're not seeing using your current sort.

Comment: Reversing the sort gives me the same folders. I still do not see the missing folders. Also, if I completely remove the folders that are displaying, I still do not see the missing folders. It tells me the directory is empty. It seems to only display this set of folders no matter what I do.

Comment: When you say you checked the properties, you looked at file permissions? Just for grins any difference 1) applying a filter or b) using DirectoryList() instead?